# How can I append a div container from an array with a for loop (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I append a div container from an array with a for loop (in JavaScript)

This is what I have tried:

```js
setInterval(function(){
  $.get("/get_room?room=" + roomCode).then((res) => {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    $(".messages_container")[0].innerHTML = "";
      for(let i=0;i<=res.room.msgs.length;i++){
        li.innerHTML = res.room.msgs[i];
        $(".messages_container")[0].appendChild(li)
      }
  });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: what kind of issue do you have with this code?

Comment: @technophyle it just says undefined

Comment: what says undefined?

Comment: my server responds with ```{"room": {"room": "happyfone","msgs": ["New Room Created.","mymessage"]}}```

Comment: @technophyle the li tag

Comment: posted an answer. hope it answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

- The li element should be created separately (not reusing the same variable) in each iteration.
- Your for loop should iterate the correct number of iterations.

See the demo:

```js
const res = {
  "room": {
    "room": "happyfone",
    "msgs": ["New Room Created.", "mymessage"]
  }
};

$(".messages_container")[0].innerHTML = "";
for (let i = 0; i < res.room.msgs.length; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = res.room.msgs[i];
  $(".messages_container")[0].appendChild(li)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="messages_container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create and append the li within the loop - otherwise you are only creating one li intead of one per message.  and because the for loop is 0 indexed - you will need to limit the loop to be less than  the length. This is because the length will always be 1 more than the index of the iteration.

Also you should be able to empty the html of the container using jQuery as well - $(".messages_container")[0].html('').

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.get("/get_room?room=" + roomCode).then((res) => {
    $(".messages_container")[0].innerHTML = "";
      for(let i=0; i< res.room.msgs.length; i++){ // note the removal of "="
        var li = document.createElement("li"); // moved the li creation to here
        li.innerHTML = res.room.msgs[i];
        $(".messages_container")[0].appendChild(li)
      }
  });
}, 2000);
```